# Cabinet door won't bevel (Archimesh addon)

Tags: bevel

I have a cabinet created with the Archimesh addon. I want to apply a bevel on the left door but it won't have an effect on it, even if I raise the value. I extruded the door to create a visual effect as you can see, looks like it has to do with that because you can see the bevel works perfectly fine on the right door that has not been touched.

P.S: I am following a tutorial where this step is supposed to work just fine.

Thanks a lot, see you!
[image]

Comment: I don't think this question is solvable without the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is that bevel modifier has a special setting "Clamp overlap", that limits bevel width by size of the smallest edge in model. You can do one of 2 things:

1) Unclick "Clamp overlap", in cost of quality of model, because it will cause  overlapping faces.

[image]

2) Limit faces with beveling, for example, by weight.

[image]

Then select edges what you want to bevel, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -> **Edge bevel  weight**

[image]